# App Store Localization

Tags: ios, localization

This is for an iPad and iPhone app.

Does localizing metadata and app name hurt app store SEO at all for an apps default localization?  Or is it just the more keywords the better?
Can my app have different names but be the same app in different countries?

I just searched for my app in Spanish from my USA iPad and it came up even though the only Spanish meta data I have is in the Spanish localization.  The name of my app came up in English though but in the Spanish localization I have a Spanish name (is there a way to check to see this as I have only been able to find my app with an English name).

Thanks.